# Clarification of "en effet" when expressing cause and consequence

Tags: grammaire

I am currently a 14-year old student studying French as a 3rd Language so I am not well-versed in it and would like to clarify some doubts.

From what I have learnt, "en effet" can be used to express a cause and consequence using the following structure:

> [consequence] + en effet + [cause / explanation]

However, from all the practices I have done, I have realised that there is always a semi-colon [;] after the consequence. This brings me to my question: Is there a need to put a semi-colon after the consequence when using en effet to express cause and consequence?

> Example: Cyril était un génie précoce; il avait en effet un Ql de 180.

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Depending on how strong you feel the two clauses are linked, you can use a coma or a period.  More, *en effet* is sometimes not placed between the two clauses, but in the middle of the second one. Self referential example:

> Utiliser cette locution n'est pas simple pour des locuteurs non-natifs. Une des difficultés de son emploi est, en effet, la variété des positions qu'il peut prendre dans la phrase.

Comment: I'm not sure how you think *en effet* can be used when the two clauses are in the same sentence. They must be linked together by a conjunction. *En effet* cannot be used as a coordinating conjunction. Do you have any example in mind?